# Will work be overwritten if done on one branch and merge a feature into that branch?

Tags: git

I have a develop branch on git. Someone made changes directly to the develop branch and committed them. I have been working on a feature branch and need to merge my changes INTO develop as well. If I merge into develop will I lose their work?

Comment: no, you are describing basic/standard usage of git

Comment: @AD7six cool, thats what I thought. Was just in slight doubt about it. thank you!